# running InstallUtil {app}/file.exe in inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to copy service files to {app} directory and then use this as a parameter in InstallUtil.exe.

Here's some part of my code :

```
[Files]
Source: WCFService.exe; DestDir: {app}
Source: WCFService.exe.config; DestDir: {app}

[Run]
Filename: {dotnet40}\InstallUtil.exe; Parameters: {app}\WCFService.exe
```

This code doesn't work (but the files are copied into {app} directory correctly). However, if I use something like this :

```
[Files]
Source: WCFService.exe; DestDir: {src}
Source: WCFService.exe.config; DestDir: {src}

[Run]
Filename: {dotnet40}\InstallUtil.exe; Parameters: WCFService.exe
```

it works correctly. Does anyone know what's going on?
I have to use inno setup.

Comment: Maybe you should put `{app}\WCFService.exe` in Quotation marks `""`? Or maybe you should set `WorkingDir` to `{app}`?

Comment: I tried it up and it worked!

Code :


[Run]
Filename: {dotnet40}\InstallUtil.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; Parameters: WCFService.exe

Thanks a lot, mate :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you could try to set `WorkingDir` parameter to `{app}` in the `[Run]` section.
Like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet40}\InstallUtil.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Parameters: "WCFService.exe"
```

Answer (score 4):

`{app}` may contain spaces, and so must be properly quoted when using it on command lines:

```
[Run]
Filename: {dotnet40}\InstallUtil.exe; Parameters: """{app}\WCFService.exe"""
```

The outermost set of quotes is for Inno itself; each pair of doubled quotes within that will end up putting a single quote on the command line.